# Rails4: How to validate image size uploaded by carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm using Rails4 and Carrierwave to upload files, and I have it working.
I have come to check the image size with the following this aritcle, [2. Model Level Validation](http://stevenyue.com/2013/04/03/validate-attachment-file-size-and-type-in-rails/).

I added `validate :image_size_validation` in models\article.rb, but `NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create` was appeared.

How can I check the image size?

Should I use `file_size_validator.rb` (refer to [How to: Validate attachment file size](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-attachment-file-size)) instead of the solution in the above article?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

\models\article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
...
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
    validate :image_size_validation
...
    private

    def image_size_validation
        errors[:image] << "should be less than 1MB" if photos.image.size > 1.megabytes
    end

end
```

\models\photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

\controllers\article_controller.rb

```
...
  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "article created!"
      redirect_to current_user #root_url
    else
        @article.build_images
       render 'new'
    end
  end
...
```

article table

```
sqlite> .schema articles
CREATE TABLE "articles" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "content" varchar(255),"user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "category_id" integer);
```

photos table

```
sqlite> .schema photos
CREATE TABLE "photos" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "article_id" integer,"image" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "bin_image" blob); #prepare bin_image for saving image as binary
```

development.log

```
Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-08 19:47:05 +0900
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"笨・, "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "article"=>{"category_id"=>"1718", "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"article_id"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x4579140 @tempfile=#<File:C:/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20141008-5252-vsv6z>, @original_filename="DSCN0721_080.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"article[photos_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"DSCN0721_080.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "1"=>{"article_id"=>""}, "2"=>{"article_id"=>""}}, "content"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"逋ｻ骭ｲ縺吶ｋ"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'xxx' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 888ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `image' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Photo:0x472f8d8>):
  app/models/article.rb:27:in `image_size_validation'
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:20:in `create'
```

**Edit**

I added `image_size_validation` in photo.rb instead of article.rb, but no error message appeared when I uploaded over 1MB image.

\models\photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

validate :image_size_validation

    private

    def image_size_validation
        #errors[:image] << "should be less than xMB" if image.size > 1.megabytes
        #add the following code instead of above line
      if image.size > 1.megabytes
        errors.add(:base, "Image should be less than 1MB")
      end

    end

end
```

\log\development.log

```
Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-11 05:50:06 +0900
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"笨・, "authenticity_token"=>"xxxx", "article"=>{"categort_id"=>"1718", "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"article_id"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x43af760 @tempfile=#<File:C:/xxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/xxxxk>, @original_filename="DSCN0721.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"article[photos_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"DSCN0721.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "1"=>{"article_id"=>""}, "2"=>{"article_id"=>""}}, "content"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"逋ｻ骭ｲ縺吶ｋ"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'xxxx' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "articles" ("content", "created_at", "category_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "test"], ["created_at", Fri, 10 Oct 2014 20:50:08 UTC +00:00], ["category_id", 1718], ["updated_at", Fri, 10 Oct 2014 20:50:08 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `image`
  [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "photos" ("article_id", "created_at", "image", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["article_id", 78], ["created_at", Fri, 10 Oct 2014 20:50:08 UTC +00:00], ["image", "xxxx.jpg"], ["updated_at", Fri, 10 Oct 2014 20:50:08 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (3.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 1306ms (ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

Comment: you should validate the file size in your `Photo` model, to show that its working you could always do `puts "Im validating"` in your  `image_size_validation` method and then look in your console to see it working

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Richlewis. I edited my question. I added `validate` in photo model, but it couldn't validate. And I can't understand `puts "Im validating"`. It would be appreciated if you could be a little more specific.

Comment: how are you outputting your error messages?

Comment: I could upload image normally which size was over 1MB. No error message was displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this in your Photo Model

```
validate :image_size_validation, :if => "image?"

def image_size_validation
    if image.size > 1.megabytes
      errors.add(:base, "Image should be less than 1MB")
    end
 end
```

remove the `private` declaration

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I edited the code, the following error appeared. `e:/xxxx/kabuhiro_app/app/models/photo.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: apologies typo on my behalf, but look at  the error, theres an `if` statement, they should always have an end

Comment: Thank you for your answer,@Richlewis. Although the above error was not displayed, I could upload image normally which size was over 1MB. No error message was still displayed.

Comment: can you show us how your outputting your errors to the view?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,@Richlewis. As I mentioned above, There is **NO** error message in the view. I can upload over 1MB image normally. I added `development.log` for a help of some kind.

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can put this.....this is the third time I've asked you... How are you capturing your errors? They don't just magically appear, they are captured in a errors object, , http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors how are you getting them to display on the front end?

Comment: Thank you for always answering my question, @Richlewis. I use 'process :resize_to_fill => [250, 250]' in the '\uploaders\image_uploader.rb'. Does 'image_size_validation' in Photo model validate the resized image, not original one? Is it not necessary to validate whether the big file size image uploaded or not when 'resize_to_fill' is used? I apologize a lot of question.

Comment: It works after removing `resize_to_fill`. Thank you for your answer and sorry for not being able to explain my intent of a question, @Richlewis.

Answer (score 5):

Since `1.0` version CarrierWave has built-in file size validation.

Install latest `carrierwave` gem

```
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
```

Add method `size_range` to provide a min size and a max size

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def size_range
    0..2.megabytes
  end
```

In model add `validates_integrity_of` to valid a file size (and content type) of an image.

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_integrity_of :image
```

Rspec spec is:

```
it 'is invalid with an image size greater 2mb' do
  image = build(:image, image: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec/support/images/image-3mb.jpg')))
  image.valid?
  expect(image.errors[:image]).to include("File size should be less than 2097152")
end
```

To make an error message more friendly override carrierwave's `check_size!` method in your `ImageUploader`.

```
 private
 def check_size!(new_file)
    size = new_file.size
    expected_size_range = size_range
    if expected_size_range.is_a?(::Range)
      if size < expected_size_range.min
        raise CarrierWave::IntegrityError, I18n.translate(:"errors.messages.min_size_error", :min_size => ApplicationController.helpers.number_to_human_size(expected_size_range.min))
      elsif size > expected_size_range.max
        raise CarrierWave::IntegrityError, I18n.translate(:"errors.messages.max_size_error", :max_size => ApplicationController.helpers.number_to_human_size(expected_size_range.max))
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great answer. I just wonder how to convert the error message *File size should be less than 2097152* to something that my users can understand. Is there a way to replace *2097152* with *0.2 MB* in the error message?

Comment: Thanks alot!
Also add this gem: `gem 'carrierwave-i18n'`